# How do I set connection flags in an extended mysqli class?

Tags: php, mysqli

When you construct a mysqli object, it opens a connection, but the constructor doesn't have the "flags" field that mysqli::real_connect has.

How do I set the flags when using the object-oriented mysqli methods? Normally I could use mysqli::init to create the mysqli object without connecting, but I'm extending the mysqli class and that would return an instance of the base class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Darn it. There's actually a specific example for this in the documentation for real_connect labeled "Object oriented style when extending mysqli class". I missed it the first time.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-connect.php

```
class foo_mysqli extends mysqli {
    public function __construct($host, $user, $pass, $db) {
        parent::init();

        // ... init settings

        if (!parent::real_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db)) {
            die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
                . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
    }
}
```